# Using Animated.timing() API in React Native to slide in/out content

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-reanimated

I have a screen in my React Native app that show/hide content based on some toggle buttons using Hooks. Everything is working fine but I'd like to improve the UI and add some animation to slide in the new content and slide out the old one.

Here's my code...

```
const [activeSwitch, setActiveSwitch] = useState(0);
...
return (
  <Scrollview>
    {activeSwitch === 1 ? (
      <View>
        <Text>SCREEN 1</Text>
      </View>
    ) : null}
    {activeSwitch === 2 ? (
      <View>
        <Text>SCREEN 2</Text>
      </View>
    ) : null}
    {activeSwitch === 3 ? (
      <View>
        <Text>SCREEN 3</Text>
      </View>
    ) : null}
  </Scrollview>
)}
```

I'm setting the state using setActiveSwitch() based on which button I click.

I've never worked with the Animation API before and tried to look at the documentation here but could not make it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i like this question, can help you but i need some time, hope its okay.

Comment: sure, no problem!

Comment: How do you want it to look
Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda similar to my [own recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470937/app-intro-slider-with-checkable-inputs-on-pages-calling-actions-from-parent-s) where I need to command a PageSlider with two buttons.

---

Anyway, if `ScrollView` is used for Vertical/Horizontal scrolling (because components are very long) it's ok, but I'd rather include the ScrollView inside the children itself, rather than wrapping everything with a single ScrollView. If it's used for animations, remove it, since it's useless.

Then, remember that `activeSwitch` will re-render the whole page and your JSX is somehow long. You could refactor your code to get an easy helper function to get your component visible.

```js
const getComponent() => {
  switch(activeSwitch) {
    case 1: return (<Screen1 />);
    case 2: return (<Screen1 />);
    ...
    default: return null;
  }
}

...

return <ScrollView>{getComponent()}</ScrollView>
```

Then to animate your view in Reanimated 3 you can leverage on props like Entering and Exiting that will animate the layout for you, when parts of the screens gets conditionally rendered:

```js
<Screen1 entering={FadeIn} exiting={FadeOut} />
```

Docs: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/layout-animations/entering-exiting-animations